# Is uplift modeling a solution to the multiple comparisons problem?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, cart, ab-test

If you want to identify a particular user segment for whom an experiment produced some lift or incremental effect over the control treatment, wouldn't it be more direct to do uplift modeling?

Uplift modeling is not generally discussed at the same time as the multiple comparisons problem, but I wonder if that’s a legacy of hypothesis testing professionals having expertise in inferential statistics, not predictive modeling. When I see A/B Testing professionals applying corrections to their hypothesis tests to be able to dis-aggregate them by test segments, it makes me wonder if there is a model from another branch of statistics that would more directly support this type of analysis. It seems that uplift modeling from predictive statistics fits the bill.

Uplift modeling basically creates 2 predictive models using decision trees: one that predicts which group A test subjects will produce the desired effect based on their attributes (age, gender, whatever) and one that does the same with group B test subjects. Uplift modeling then integrates these 2 predictive models to produce a single predictive model of test subjects whose propensity to produce the desired effect is increased the most by the treatment applied to group B.

Here's some introductions to uplift modeling:

- [Uplift modeling: The next big thing in predictive analytics](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2472504/social-business/uplift-modeling--the-next-big-thing-in-predictive-analytics.html)
- [Uplift modeling FAQ](http://scientificmarketer.com/2007/09/uplift-modelling-faq.html)
- [Real-World Uplift Modelling withSignificance-Based Uplift Trees](http://stochasticsolutions.com/pdf/sig-based-up-trees.pdf)

Doesn't this essentially answer the question that researchers have in mind when they dis-aggregate their hypothesis test results by attributes of their test subjects? Their basic question is: For which subset of test subjects does this treatment produce an effect?

Comment: It would be helpful to me if you could distinguish between uplift modeling and modeling using interactions/multiplicative effects/subgroup effects.  I have a feeling that, just as "statistical analysis" in many circles has come to be called "predictive analytics," so "modeling using interactions" has, in a marketing or customer-behavior-inducing context, come to be called "uplift modeling."

Comment: Uplift modelling is related to AB/ Hypothesis testing in the way that it could provide an indication if any confounding variable is causing an increase in the uplift in the test group. See [Application to A/B and multivariate testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uplift_modelling#Application_to_A/B_and_multivariate_testing).